# VBA-charts: how to read the formula from a chart Series

Tags: excel, vba

how can I read back the formula that has been assigned to any of the chart series properties?
i.e. when I have a simple x-y scatter chart, I can assign a formula to the Name property

```
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=Sheet2!$D$1"
Debug.Print ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name 
' DOES NOT Print =Sheet2!$D$1, but the value in that cell
```

the problem is, that when I read it later, it always returns the value of the formula, not the formula itself.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FullSeriesCollection` is for Excel 2013 which I do not have currently. However, the following code displays the series formula in Excel 2010 and it should, I believe, work for 2013:

```
Sub Blah1()
    Dim cht As ChartObject

    Set cht = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1)
    MsgBox cht.Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
End Sub
```

If the chart is not an embedded chart then the following equivalent code (for a Chart sheet) also works:

```
Sub Blah2()
    Dim cht As Chart

    Set cht = ActiveChart
    MsgBox cht.SeriesCollection(1).Formula
End Sub
```

Comment: I came up with `Formula` also, but noticed, in 2010` that it sometimes reverts to the contents/Value of the cell. Couldn't figure out the pattern of when it happened.

Comment: @DougGlancy I haven't encountered that issue. Please re-comment if you discover the cause.

Comment: thanks - actually I've tried this, but when I accessed the Formula property, I got an application-defined error - thus I thought that I need to use the Name/Values properties.
It turned out, that one of the references in Values was invalid (#Ref). I didn't see this problem, because the chart still returned the last valid data!
Now that this is corrected, accessing the Formula is fine and exactly what I needed.